# "Failure creating named object" both when installing Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04, but 20.04 is installed nevertheless while on 18 the screen freezes compl

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, bios

I have burnt now two USBs one with Ubuntu 20.04.06 and one with 18.04.06. I had 20.04 in dual boot for a long time but now need to downgrade to 18.04 and decided to uninstall 20 completely and install 18.04 from scratch. But when the time for booting from the USB comes, this error message comes several times: ***"ASPI BIOS Erros (bug): Failure creating named object / ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog(20190816/psob ject-221)"*** and then the screen freezes completely.I waited some time, but it doesnt proceed to the installation of 18.04.06. I looked it up and shaw that it had to do smth with the gpu drivers (NVDIA Geforce gtx) and i installed the latest drivers but the same thing kept happening. I switched back to the 20.04 USB and tried to install again the 20.04 version and saw that the same message came to terminal, but after some time it proceed to disk checking and then the installation screen popped so the process works fine. So do you know whats the difference and if there's something that can be done?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Those errors aren't a problem, but your Nvida graphics might be. Try adding `nomodeset` as a kernel parameter and see if you can boot then. Installing the latest drivers won't do anything as far as booting a live system.

Comment: Or you can try the second option (safe graphics) which should be more or less the same as `nomodeset`. Also we need to remind you that Ubuntu 18.04 has less than one year of support left and no, you don't need it, no one does, you just think you do.

Comment: @Esther Thank you very much for the speedy and helpful reply. After adding the nomodeset parameter it worked and the screen didnt freeze and its installing right now normally! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you too very much,  unfortunately i didnt see a safe graphics choice like in other version but after adding the nomodeset parameter it worked as i mentioned. Maybe its true that i dont need the previous version but thats my supervisors call, lets see. Thanks though for the tip and the big help!